# jQuery Mobile - How to have a transparent background for the slider?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to make a jQuery Mobile slider that has a transparent background. I would like the little "pip" on the slider to stay the same, but the purpose of this is to have the slider on top of a gradient image so that the background image could show through. Do I have to use themeroller for this? I took a look at it but couldn't figure out how to do transparency.

jQuery mobile slider docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Like this? http://puu.sh/4Z8Ht.jpg

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for! Preferably without the blue aura around the circle but that might be another question altogether. Would you mind linking me the changes you made to get this? If you used any certain resources to find out how to do this that would be appreciated too, I might have to do a lot more styling down the road and it would be helpful to know how to do this stuff myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue aura around the circle is something chrome specific. I think it can be turned off by using `outline:0;`

or failing that,

`box-shadow:none;`

However, to get rid of the bar (at least visually), I used:

`border:none;`

and

`background:transparent;`

on the class that was the slider (in that page's case, it was `div.ui-slider`). That was all it took to get rid of it.